# Unable to invoke the exports function from bpl

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I using Delphi XE, i've the following setup:

Both **Mydll.dll** and **Package1.bpl** (runtime package) contains Unit3.pas

```
unit Unit3;

interface

implementation

uses Dialogs;

procedure TestProc(const S: string); stdcall;
begin
  MessageDlg(S, mtInformation, [mbOK], 0);
end;

exports TestProc;

end.
```

**Case 1:**

```
procedure TestProc(const S: string); stdcall; external 'mydll.dll';

procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TestProc('Button3');
end;
```

**Case 2:**

```
procedure TestProc(const S: string); stdcall; external 'Package1.bpl';

procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TestProc('Button3');
end;
```

**Case 3:**

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var H: THandle;
    P: procedure(const S: string); stdcall;
begin
  H := LoadPackage('Package1.bpl');
  try
    @P := GetProcAddress(H, PChar('TestProc'));
    if Assigned(P) then
      P('Button3');
  finally
    UnloadPackage(H);
  end;
end;
```

**Case 1** and **Case 3 passed** but **Case 2** will **raise Access Violation**.

My question as below, 


1. Case 2 is not supported? 

2. Except the Case 3, is there anyway to invoke the TestProc from Package1.bpl similar as Case1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the case 2 is supported but you must call the [`LoadPackage`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE/en/SysUtils.LoadPackage) function too to load the package in memory.

try this code

```
procedure TestProc(const S: string); stdcall;  external 'Package1.bpl';


var
  hPackage : Cardinal;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   TestProc('Button3');
end;


initialization
  hPackage := LoadPackage('Package1.bpl');
finalization
  if hPackage<>0 then 
  UnloadPackage(hPackage);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. The 1st solution will raise Access Violation if click the button 2nd time, but 2nd solution works fine no matter how many times i click the button.

Comment: @lmengyew I delete the first solution (and just keep the second). the  Access Violation exception was raised in the `LoadPackage` line,  because the package is already loaded the second time which you call it.

Answer (score 0):

For case 2, you could also just simply build your project with runtime packages and include Package1 in the list of runtime packages for your project (in Project Options\Packages\Runtime packages). Then you can remove the import (`external` declaration) and just use the unit which contains the function.